# Django multiple foreign key to a same table

Tags: python, django

I need to log the transaction of the item movement in a warehouse.  I've 3 tables as shown in the below image.  However Django response error:

ERRORS:
chemstore.ItemTransaction: (models.E007) Field 'outbin' has column name 'bin_code_id' that is used by another field.

which is complaining of multiple uses of the same foreign key.  Is my table design problem?  or is it not allowed under Django?  How can I achieve this under Django?  thankyou

[DB design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F29Fg.jpg)

[Models]

```
class BinLocation(models.Model):
    bin_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.bin_code}"

    class Meta:
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=['bin_code'])]


class ItemMaster(models.Model):
    item_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    long_desc = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    helper_qty = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.item_code}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Item"
        verbose_name_plural = "Items"
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=['item_code'])]


class ItemTransaction(models.Model):
    trace_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=False)
    item_code = models.ForeignKey(
        ItemMaster, related_name='trans', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    qty = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)
    action = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=ACTION, blank=False, null=False)
    in_bin = models.ForeignKey(
        BinLocation, related_name='in_logs', db_column='bin_code_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    out_bin = models.ForeignKey(
        BinLocation, related_name='out_logs', db_column='bin_code_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    remarks = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.trace_code} {self.datetime} {self.item_code} {dict(ACTION)[self.action]} {self.qty} {self.unit} {self.in_bin} {self.out_bin}"
```

Comment: db_column='bin_code_id' ... you attempt to name 2 fields in database with the same name... relational db schema can not contain fields with same name... how would it make a difference?

Comment: yes. It will not allow two duplicate key. Why you need two (in_bin and out_bin ) duplicate column ?

Comment: thankyou, which means my table design problem.  sorry for the newbie question.  then, how can I achieve if both in_bin and out_bin are having the same set of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for everyone helped.  According to Aleksei and Tabaane, it is my DB design issue (broken the RDBMS rule) rather than Django issue.  I searched online and find something similar: [ONE-TO-MANY DB design pattern](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69011/many-one-to-many-relationships-between-two-tables)

In my case, I should store in bin and out bin as separated transaction instead of both in and out in a single transaction.  This is my solution. thankyou.

p.s. alternative solution: I keep in bin and out bin as single transaction, but I don't use foreign key for bins, query both in bin and out bin for the bin selection by client application.

Answer (score 3):

you have same `db_column` in two fields so change it

```
    in_bin = models.ForeignKey(
        BinLocation, related_name='in_logs', db_column='bin_code_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    out_bin = models.ForeignKey(
        BinLocation, related_name='out_logs', db_column='other_bin_code', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False) /*change db_column whatever you want but it should be unique*/
```

Comment: Thx Pruthvi, it prompted for error: OperationalError
Exception Value: 
no such column: chemstore_itemtransaction.bin_code_id1  I suppose the db_column should point to the key of foreign table key which is not just a name to identify?

Comment: have done `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: yes sure, both makemigrations and migrate successful without complain, however when I access to the page it prompted the above error

Comment: delete all migrations files and then try

Comment: yes, i used to delete all migrations files before makemigrations and migrate.  I suppose the db_column should point to something exist, rather than a name.

Answer (score 1):

If are linked to the same model name, You should use different related_name for each foreign_key filed . here is the exemple :

```
    address1 = models.ForeignKey(Address, verbose_name=_("Address1"),related_name="Address1", null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    address2 = models.ForeignKey(Address, verbose_name=_("Address2"),related_name="Address2", null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```